# Will I be granted a German business visa if my company started just a few years ago?

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, business-travel

My company is 1-2 years old. Can I apply for a 2-week German business visa with 1 or 2 year's tax returns? All my statements of accounts are fine. What is the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 3):

If the rest of your application looks fine, you can do that.

For a business trip, you have to explain where you are going and whom you will meet. (For a tourist trip, you would have to explain where you are going and what you want to see. Same kind of visa.)

Either way, you *personally* should have stable finances which make it appear likely that you will return to your homeland.